# retrieve stock numbers via some data feed

Tags: api, finance, stocks

Is there any data feed, xml or api that will allow you to retrieve all the stocks (maybe limited to USA) and their current prices (not realtime).  I know I can hit google or yahoo to get the price of one stock but I would like to get all of them.

and it has to be free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webservice to get stock quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773461/webservice-to-get-stock-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a service which provides prices for "all the stocks" as it is hard to define "all". Do you want to receive all listed stocks? It would be 2000+ for NYSE and another 2000+ for NASDAQ.

The closest I am aware it mutli-ticker request from [Yahoo!](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm), but you need to provide tickers in the query. (Beware of the Yahoo! Web Services [limits](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/rate.html))

Second solution is to use Google API, build a portfolio with required positions (tickers) and query data through it. Although sounds simpler, you must be aware that Google Finance API is [deprecated](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html) (but not shut down yet).